# Assembly.CreateInstance() or AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap() doesn't work for IronPython class

Tags: ironpython

I've created a simple python class, and I'm passing it's type to a .Net assembly that tries to instantiate it using:

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName);
```

This throws a FileNotFoundException.

```
type.Assembly.FullName == 'Snippets.scripting, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I can find the Assembly by name in AppDomain.CurrentDomain, so I believe I'm OK there.

To further narrow it down I tried:

```
type.Assembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName)
```

In this case I get a MissingMethodException.  Here's a simple example that demonstrates this:

```
IronPython 2.7 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.239
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import clr
>>> import System
>>> class foo(System.Object):
...   pass
...
>>> type = clr.GetClrType(foo)
>>> type.Assembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Constructor on type 'IronPython.NewTypes.System.Object_1$1' not
found.
>>> for ctor in type.GetConstructors():
...   print ctor
...
Void .ctor(IronPython.Runtime.Types.PythonType)
```

.Net only sees 1 constructor, and that requires an argument.  I need my class to not require any arguments so theat CreateInstance will work.  I can't modify the CreateInstance call to add arguments - that's not my code.

Either I'm barking up the wrong tree at this point, or I need a way to create an IronPython class that has a constructor that doesn't require any arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IronPython classes aren't normal .NET classes, so treating them as such doesn't really work. ([explanation](http://devhawk.net/2009/04/21/__clrtype__-metaclasses-ironpython-classes-under-the-hood/)) IronPython does support a `__clrtype__` hook, similar to the standard `__metaclass__` hook, that allows the IronPython compiler to generate a "real" .NET class to back the Python class and enable scenarios such as yours.

Working with `__clrtype__` directly is quite difficult, as it's a low-level hook. The [ClrType sample](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/36280#DownloadId=116513) contains `clrtype.py`, which makes working with `__clrtype__` significantly easier; take a look at `sample.py` in the zip for an example of how to use it.

This is an area of IronPython that hasn't gotten the attention it deserves, so there might still be some rough edges.

Comment: Thanks! This works great for the 2nd problem.  type.Assembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName) works perfectly now.  
  
Unfortunately, my original problem still stands.  I'm still getting a FileNotFound exception when trying to call it through AppDomain, so I still have some more digging to do.  
  
I'm currently looking into doing this http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/dynamically_compiling.shtml to dynamically compile a C# class.  I would create a dll but I have some other problems with that.

Comment: Success! I needed to add a ResolveHandler to locate the assembly, now this works. AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveHandler